# Linear congruential generator with non constant increment

Tags: randomness, cryptanalysis

Consider [this random generator function](https://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/src/test/SDL_test_random.c).

A simplified version is provided below (this is C++, mind that "seed" is a reference):

```
uint32_t Rand(uint64_t& seed)
{
    seed = 1683268614LL * (seed & 0xffffffff) + (seed >> 32);
    return seed & 0xffffffff;
}
```

For those unfamiliar with C++: `&` denotes bit-wise AND, `LL` as a suffix denotes `signed long long` (signed 64-bit usually), `>>` denotes plain bit-shift, the `uint64_t&` in the header denotes that the input is a reference to an unsigned 64-bit integer, that is, updates also apply outside the function.

This is almost a linear congruential generator (LCG), the only difference is that the increment is not a constant, but a part of the seed itself.

My question is on the security of this algorithm, since LCGs are very easy to break.

Does using a non constant increment improve or decrease security? How could this be cracked other than by bruteforceing it?

Comment: What this algorithm does: It takes the seed, takes the lower 32-bit, multiplies them by some constant and then adds the upper 32-bit of the seed, writes the full value back and returns the lower 32-bit, all in $\mathbb Z_{2^{64}}$

Comment: Also note that neither `seed` nor the other intermediate values exceed the representable range of signed 64-bit integers.

Comment: Have you performed a randomness test on it using a reputable tool? If it fails, it's not really usable for cryptography in the first place...

Comment: @Paul Uszak: Having failed to exhibit a short cycle by Floyd's cycle finding after $>2^{42}$ evaluations from 6 haphazard seeds, and given its structure, I'm ready to bet this generator passes many existing randomness tests. Yet, as [shown by poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48788/555), it is not really usable for cryptography. This an example illustrating the fact that randomness tests are not a reliable mean to detect that a RNG is unsuitable for cryptography.

Comment: @fgrieu Just thought I'd ask to save you having to do a test run. Frankly, I didn't think that it would pass Diehard(er) but if you say it does...

Comment: @Paul Uszak: of course I can't guess the result of Dieharder by glancing at the generator! Thus I run dieharder (3.31.1 as packaged in mint) against that generator (twice, with seeds 42 and 2017), `-a` option. Out of 228 tests: 0 FAIL, 5 WEAK (3 for one seed, 2 for the other, for different tests). My _passes many existing randomness tests_ holds, and dieharder does not clearly eliminate the generator as broken. One run of `dieharder -g AES_OFB -a` just gave me 5 WEAK out of 114 tests (seed 1155732807), thus I consider reasonable to ignore whatever WEAK alarms dieharder raised.

Answer (score 6):

The state can be trivially recovered from two consecutive output (and hence all further outputs can be predicted).

For the first output, the system updates the seed to $\text{seed}_1$, and then outputs the lower 32 bits of $\text{seed_1}$, which we'll call $\text{output}_1$

For the second output, the system first computes:

> $\text{seed}_2$ = 1683268614LL * $\text{output}_1$ + ($\text{seed}_1$ >> 32)

Then, the system outputs $\text{output}_2$, the lower 32 bits of $\text{seed}_2$.

Hence, if the attacker computes:

> $\text{output}_2$ - 1683268614LL * $\text{output}_1$ $\bmod{2^{32}}$

That gives him the upper 32 bits of $\text{seed}_1$.  With the entire value of $\text{seed}_1$, the rest of the sequence can be predicted.

With a standard LCG, you can also reconstruct internal states, but not this easily...